# Why I cannot mixin an assignment method from a module

Tags: ruby, class, module, mixins, assignment-operator

Suppose I have a module like this:

```
module MyAssigments
  def dummy_assignment=(value)
    puts "it's not assigned #{value}"
  end
end
```

and a class that includes it like this:

```
class MyClass
  include MyAssigments
  def x=(value)
     dummy_assignment=(value)
  end
end
```

then

```
o = MyClass.new
o.x="anything"
```

does not print anything on screen, why ?

Answer (score 3):

Ruby has a syntax/paring quirk here: using an assginemnt method for `self` has to be explicitly qualified thus:

```
  def x=(value)
     self.dummy_assignment=value
  end
```

without the `self.` part, it is assumed by ruby to be an assignment to a local variable.

Comment: Ok that works but does not answer my question. Why I cannot reference the module method from within the class ?